# css grid minmax between fixed size and fraction

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to split a div into left and right parts. The left side holds size of min 100px and max 10% of the whole width. The right side fills up the rest space. My code is as below:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(100px 1fr) 9fr;
}

.left {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

.right {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But, What I've observed is that both the left and right div have the width of 50%. Why?

Comment: missing a `,` between the value if minmax

Comment: yeah, embarrassed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(100px ,1fr) 9fr;
}

.left {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

.right {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">Hi</div>
    <div class="right">Hello</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please don't answer when it's a simple typo error, flag/close the question